# How to save a folder from FolderPicker in StorageFolder?

Tags: c#, storagefolder

When i try to do this:

```
        folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

it show me error:

> Error 2   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
>   Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing
>   its return type to 'Task'.    C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\RobimyProjekt\RobimyProjekt\ImageBrowser.xaml.cs.

When i deleted "await" it show me another error:

> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation' to
>   'Windows.Storage.StorageFolder'   C:\Users\Lukasz\Documents\Visual
>   Studio
>   2012\Projects\RobimyProjekt\RobimyProjekt\ImageBrowser.xaml.cs    61  36  RobimyProjekt.

What's going on? That code is from msdna and i using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: How is  your function (which contains this code) defined?

Comment: private void pickFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
   //code from earlier post
}

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to use async keyword for await.

```
private async void pickFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
    folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    folderPicker.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.List;
    folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
    StorageFolder folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
    if(folder != null)
    {
         StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The below worked for me. It took me a few days to figure this out; but, for my own learning project, I wanted to see if I could make a Folder, File, and then read from it. I was, just, able to create my folder in my designated path by doing the below.

Granted, I am passing a Textbox object as a parameter; but, disregarding that, the following works for me when I try and create my folder using a `FolderPicker` and a `StorageFolder`.

```
public static async Task<string> createDirectory(TextBox parmTextBox)
{
    string folderName = parmTextBox.Text.Trim();

    // Section: Allows the user to choose their folder.
    FolderPicker fpFolder = new FolderPicker();
    fpFolder.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop;
    fpFolder.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    fpFolder.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");
    StorageFolder sfFolder = await fpFolder.PickSingleFolderAsync();

    if (sfFolder.Name != null)
    {
        // Gives the StorageFolder permissions to modify files in the specified folder.
        Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("CSharp_Temp", sfFolder);

        // creates our folder
        await sfFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName);

        // returns a string of our path back to the user
        return string.Concat(sfFolder.Path, @"\", folderName); 
    }
    else
    {
        MessageDialog msg = new MessageDialog("Need to choose a folder.");
        await msg.ShowAsync();
        return "Error: Choose new folder.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @zx485 for editing some of my white spaces and for "a FolderPicker" and "a StorageFolder"

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
private async void (pickFolder(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Listening to the advice in the error message may also be a good idea:

> Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

The `Task` return type makes the method "awaitable".

The `void` solution as suggested in the other answers works too, but yields a 'fire & forget' solution. Recommended practice is to actually return a `Task` so that if the caller wishes to do something with, e.g., exceptions resulting from your method this is possible.

To quote from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx:

> *"To summarize this first guideline, you should prefer async Task to async void. Async Task methods enable easier error-handling, composability and testability."*